# How to convert a xml symfony services file into yaml

Tags: xml, symfony, yaml, redactor

I'm trying to adapt this bundle :
https://github.com/AStepanov/RedactorBundle
Because i need to make the imperavi image upload work but it is not updated anymore...

Right now i'm trying to adapt the services file into yaml because i can't import the xml into my yaml file.

```
<parameters>

    <parameter key="redactor.service.class">Stp\RedactorBundle\Model\RedactorService</parameter>

</parameters>

<services>
    <service id="redactor.service" class="%redactor.service.class%">
        <call method="setContainer">
            <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
        </call>
    </service>

    <service id="form.type.redactor" class="Stp\RedactorBundle\Form\Type\RedactorType">
        <argument type="service" id="redactor.service" />
        <tag name="form.type" alias="redactor" />
    </service>

</services>
```

So if anyone could tell me how to translate this into yaml, i'd be very grateful !

I actually already asked for any method to make it work but got no answer, so by the way if you know how to make the imperavi redactor image upload work feel free to tell me !

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
parameters:
    redactor.service.class: Stp\RedactorBundle\Model\RedactorService

services:
    redactor.service:
        class: %redactor.service.class%
        calls:
            - [setContainer, [@service_container]]

    form.type.redactor:
        class: Stp\RedactorBundle\Form\Type\RedactorType
        arguments: [@redactor.service]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: redactor }
```